# Terminal/Console fonts in Jetbrains products (Linux)

Tags: intellij-idea, ubuntu-14.04, clion

The problem I have affects all Jetbrains products (Android Studio, CLion, Idea, etc..), on my Kubuntu 14.04.

When I set fonts for editor and embedded terminal, the IDEs correctly set the editor fonts, but leave terminal with an ugly font.
This happens either if I select different fonts for editor and terminal, or if I select same font for both.

[image]

Any workaround for that? Thanks.

## EDIT:

#### Problem automatically solved after a dist-upgrade. Usual Ubuntu crap.

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: In the attached image, you are viewing DejaVu Sans Mono in the Editor. I don't know what font console uses, but I tried many monospaced and TT fonts in the setting window. Even reloading default settings and reinstall the IDEs doesn't change this damn console font.